# how to make visual studio code to split view between debug console and terminal

Tags: visual-studio

[image: visual studio console]

How can I make Visual Studio split the view of terminal and debug console so that I can see both of these at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: It seems it is available already. I'm at version: 1.63.2. I'm not sure how I ended up there, I came here to see how to unsplit now.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62948226/1097444