# how to keep terminal, debug console and output screens in simultaneous view in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to keep "Terminal", "Debug Console" and "Output" screens in view at the same time (split view) in Visual Studio Code.

Someone has asked a similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272127/vscode-how-to-display-both-output-window-and-debug-console)

Comment: havent figured out how to keep all these screens simultaneously in view but I mapped my keybindings for "Terminal", "Output", "Debug Console" and related actions like clearing the console to a set of keys that I can easily remember.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Holding the mouse over Output tab name for ex. and dragging to either the left or right to the area of the other panels the Output will snap into place.

[image]

Comment: Just a note - in my case Terminal window got stretched. Pressing F1 and running ``> Developer - Reload Window`` fixed the issue.